# Is it possible to shorten an OR statement with multiple conditions on the same variable?

Tags: c#

Is there a way of shortening `if(a=="bcd" || a=="efg")`?

Because the conditions are both on `a` It would be nice to write something like `if(a=="bcd"||"efg")` and contract the statement. I know I could write something custom to handle it, but was wondering if there is anything built into C# that would accomplish it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With [C# 9's patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements), you can write:

```
if (a is "bcd" or "efg")
{

}
```

Comment: This compiles to identical code to `if (a == "bcd" || a == "efg")`, so it should.

Comment: It works with any const value, so it only works for types which can be consts. That is, the built-in types excluding `object`